# Spark(scala): converting a JSON string to dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

### I want the result of this api to be converted into a dataframe

```
val url = api

val result = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString

val df = spark.read.json(result).toDF()
```

In the above code I cannot just call result. Is there any way that the result is converted to dataframe?

Comment: Please provide format of data in your result. In case you have json in each row, Ideally you will need to convert each row into case class etc

Comment: data for the result:{"data1":52,"data2":54,"data":[{"time":1462680000,"text":"abc"}}

Comment: i am not using sqlContext.. is there any other way

Answer (score 3):

There is a number of ways you can create dataFrame in spark.

**Example 1:**

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setMaster("local[2]")
  .setAppName("SomeApp")

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("basic example")
  .config(conf)
  .getOrCreate()

val df = spark.read.json("/Users/user/Sources/basesample/data.json")

df.show()

spark.close()
```

Its from standard documentation:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

**Example 2**: Here is code which does this more in the manual fashion.

I use json4s for conversion from json -> case class

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

case class Data(data1:Int, data2:Int)

val json = parse("""{"data1":52,"data2":54}""");

// Convert json string to collection of case classes
val row = json.extract[Data]

val rdd : RDD[Data] = sc.parallelize( Seq(row) )

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame( rdd)

sc.stop()
```